# Is there a browser tool to show a quick overview of headings information of a website?

Tags: html, plugins, accessibility, browser-plugin

Sometimes you need a quick overview of all used html headings (h1, h2, h3, ...) of a website. Yes actually you could take a look into the source code to get it but that's not really a quick overview.

Many webdeveloper know Chromiumbrowser's nice tool called "Web Developer". The tool enables you to outline the headings but the outlines colors does not allow a conclusion of the heading number or the heading hierarchy.

So that brings me to the question if there is a Firefox, Chromium or other Browser's tool to show a quick overview of headings information of a website ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) addon for Firefox and [Web Developer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) extension for Chrome, that does your exact work. Also, there is one more tool called [WAVE Toolbar](https://web.archive.org/web/20151108093344/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wave-toolbar/), that does the heading count and many such things related to accessibility.

#### WAVE Toolbar

[image]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.net](https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/previews/full/19/19298.png?modified=1331247702))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.net](https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/previews/full/19/19802.png?modified=1331247702))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.net](https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/previews/full/19/19803.png?modified=1331247702))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.net](https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/previews/full/19/19804.png?modified=1331247702))</sub>

Comment: So, you are going to validate your own HTML. You can do it in one single browser. Chrome has a lot of accessibility issues as been given in their bug reports. So, it is a waste of time, as Chrome constantly evolves and develops itself. It is not stable in terms of offering standards, but is trying to maintain something. Correct me if I am wrong, @ChristianMichael.

Comment: Could you please remove the webdeveloper screenshot and the webdeveloper text ? I tried it by my self but it seems I can not do it. The Wave Toolbar is the answer that a would remark as accepted then.

Comment: Using Web Developer addon, toggle the "Outline › Show Element Tag Names when Outlining" and "Outline › Outline Headers" options; It's a bit quirky but generally that will display the heading level.

Comment: @MichelJoanisse I don't understand.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Once you've installed the Web Developer addon for Firefox, enable the "Outline › Show Element Tag Names when Outlining" and "Outline › Outline Headers" options. Doing so will add a heading level indicator (e.g. h2) beside all headers on the page. Same applies to Chrome but some of the option names slightly differ. http://prntscr.com/9pndo7

Comment: @MichelJoanisse Wave does that when I answered this, there was no Web Dev Toolbar at that time.

Comment: I've had the Web Developer toolbar in Seamonkey (Firefox) for years and I never knew it could do that! I've been scouring the source code this whole time. For reference, it's under "Information - View Document Outline" - it lists the headings nested in order with little tags denoting what heading it is (H1, H2 etc) beside each. It also notifies you of missing heading levels, which is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

While there are many browser extensions and bookmarklets to display a headings outline the way it is defined in the pure HTML source code, none (as far as I know) of them displays the outline the same way a screen reader does (which actually is what we are interested in most of the times).

Some background: to maintain good accessibility in web pages, the whole web page has to be organised in a valid and meaningful headings structure. This could look like this:

```
H1 Navigation
H1 Content: Here comes the "real" title and content of the current page
  H2 Content sub section 1
  H2 Content sub section 2
    H3 Content sub section 2.1
  etc.
H1 Related
  H2 News
    H3 News 1
    H3 News 2
    H3 News 3
```

Often times, in a graphical design, many of these headings are omitted (e.g. Navigation or Related) and their meaning is transmitted through the graphical structure of the page. Nonetheless, non-graphical user agents (like e.g. a screen reader) rely on those headings, so they should still exist in the HTML source code and only hidden visually for graphical user agents ("normal" web browsers).

Now, there are two ways of hiding something visually from a web page:

First of all, we can use the CSS properties `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`. What some people don't know: **Using these properties, screen readers also omit the hidden content**. So this is **not** a good way to hide content that screen readers should still see, and so is **not** a suitable way of hiding headings for our purposes.

The second way is to move the content that is to be hidden out of the view port. This is typically done by something like `position: absolute, left: 10000px, width: 1px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden` (there are a lot of variations of this available on the net, but they all basically do the same). So typically you define a CSS class like `.visually_hidden` with the attributes above and assign this class to the headings that you want to hide **visually** (but not from screen readers).

```
H1 Navigation.visually_hidden
H1 Content
  H2 Content sub section 1
  H2 Content sub section 2
    H3 Content sub section 2.1
  etc.
H1 Related.visually_hidden
  H2 News
    H3 News 1
    H3 News 2
    H3 News 3
```

Now, back to the original topic!

As pointed out before, the mentioned headings outline tools/extensions all **do not differentiate** between visually and completely hidden elements (in fact, they don't care about CSS at all)! So they are only useful to a limited extent. (Please correct me if I'm wrong or if anybody knows an extension that implements this functionality.)

If you need to see the headings outline the way a screen user perceives it through a screen reader, you will have to install a screen reader yourself (e.g. NVDA which is free) and use its internal heading outline.

**Update**

It seems that the Web Accessibility Toolbar of Internet Explorer respects the afore mentioned display/visibility CSS attributes in its "Structure => Headings Structure" functionality, so it seems to be suitable for displaying heading hierarchies the way they really are.

Answer (score -1):

You could try and install firebug its a firefox addon the address is: http://getfirebug.com/

This is a powerfull web development tool. : )